# can Ijust replace /dev/ptmx, /dev/pts/* and fix the terminal issue after deleting one of these files?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Deleted the pts file `ptmx` at `/dev/ptmx` and cannot launch the terminal. Getting the error:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
```

and

```
Text was empty (or contained only whitespace)
```

tried downloading the file `/dev/ptmx`,and putting it back at the `/dev/` folder but running into permissions problems. when I change the permissions before moving or copying the file over, it says it the copied over file is a read only file. Guess the permissions are not sticking even though they look as though they are, when I check back. Or something else is happening.

Really, really do not want to reinstall Ubuntu.
For the record I deleted the file(s) they are not missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see that `/dev/pts` is a pseudo file system:

```
$ mount | grep 'on /dev/pts'
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
```

Ergo: there's no place on your harddrive where these files are. They are virtual files that represent something in the operating system.

I doubt that somebody has thought of implementing the creation of new files as the operating system.

I would bet that simply restarting the machine will reset the operating system back to the normal state, and these "files" will appear again.

Comment: Really!!!   "I would bet that simply restarting the machine will reset the operating system back to the normal state, and these "files" will appear again."

Comment: FYI: I have no access to the terminal at all. It's stuck on those error messages.

Comment: @wemes Did you restart?

Comment: went for restarting, but no go. Terminal still has same error mesgs.

Comment: @wemes Hard reboot. Just turn the machine off, and then back on in a few seconds.

Comment: @wemes You should consider accepting the answer, so that it can help somebody else.

Comment: It worked just great. Three hours in and  you solved this in what 3 mins.  Thanks again. Accepted the answer.

Comment: @v010dya in the olden days, before pseudo filesystems, we used `mknod` to create device-nodes. According to `man` it still exists, so maybe that could creuate the deleted device files - though it requires that you know the major and minor numbers ... a reboot is probably faster and more safe.